# How to localize a robot in a pre-loaded map in ROS?

Tags: navigation, kinect, ros

I am using Kinect sensor to help robot navigate by avoiding obstacle. I used "freenect_launch" package to get the depth_image from Kinect sensor and converted it to laserscan data using "depthimage_to_laserscan" package. Now, as I have my laser scan data, I want to use it to create a static map of the environment without using odometry data as my robot does not supply odometry data. I then want to load that static map each time in robot navigation. As my environment does not change much I do not want to create map dynamically. I was going through "hector_mapping" and found out that it does not require odometry data. I was able to generate a map with hector_mapping and have saved it using "map_saver". Is there any way that I can now load that map everytime to navigate my robot?